# Eslint and VueJS files. Throwing errors but not fixing them

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, eslint

I have a strange issue with Eslint.
It is throwing errors on Vue files, but not fixing any of them.

I have checked all config etc.

It is working for js files, but not working for Vue files.
It is really strange that it is throwing errors on them, but not fixing them. It is all about easy fixes like semicolons etc (just moved to ES6 and Eslint so need to clean up code) so it easily fixing them normally.

What can be the cause?

Comment: Hard to say without examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found why.
Basically, ESLINT is not able to fix errors when using any loaders.
In my case it is vue loader.
They are still working on that in ESLINT team to find the way to handle fix with loaders.

Comment: Is there a fix available now for this? I'm having the same issue right now.