# How to use eslint autofix in .vue?

Tags: vue.js, eslint

I want to use autofix in `.vue` file, but Eslint only show the errors, no autofix.

How do I configure the `.eslintrc` to make it work?

Answer (score 11):

Try to use it with specifying files extensions

```
eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src
```

Answer (score 5):

It will not work.
I had exactly the same issue and asked this question here (surprised you haven't found it).
I also asked them on Github and the answer is that they still not came with solution to use fix with plugins (vue-loader).

[Eslint and VueJS files. Throwing errors but not fixing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40291818/eslint-and-vuejs-files-throwing-errors-but-not-fixing-them?noredirect=1#comment67842748_40291818)

Here is thread on Github of Eslint: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/7456#issuecomment-256757117

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Vue.js 3, in your root directory, create a file `vue.config.js`, if not exists already, and insert:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('eslint')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].fix = true
        return args
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: that setting creates an endless compiling loop when i execute "npm run serve". I guess its because of some issues that ESLint cannot fix and then it retries it again and again. Any setting to prevent that?